# SQL Server How to combine 3 queries into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to condense the following three queries into one query and out put the totals into 3 columns.  Oh and how do I make it so I don't have to declare the date.  I want it to "know" the current date, month, and year.

```
DECLARE @myDate as datetime
SET @myDate = '2015-01-1'
select SUM(Amount) as 'Day Total' 
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(day,1,@myDate)

select SUM(Amount) as 'Month Total' 
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(MONTH,1,@myDate)

select SUM(Amount) as 'Day Total' 
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(year,1,@myDate)
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks!

Thanks for all the super fast responses!  This is now solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, then something like this ought to work:

```
declare @today date = convert(date, getdate());
select
    [Day Total]   = sum(case when [AccountingDate] >= @today and [AccountingDate] < dateadd(day,   1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
    [Month Total] = sum(case when [AccountingDate] >= @today and [AccountingDate] < dateadd(month, 1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
    [Year Total]  = sum(case when [AccountingDate] >= @today and [AccountingDate] < dateadd(year,  1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end)
from
    [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay];
```

Note that `[Month Total]` and `[Year Total]` don't give the sums of the entries that occur within the current month/year, but rather the sum of the entries that occur within a month/a year of today's date. I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it seems consistent with the original queries.

**UPDATE:** As suggested by D Stanley below, you can simplify this a bit since you know that the date ranges that compose the `[Day Total]` and `[Month Total]` sums are enclosed entirely within the date range that composes the `[Year Total]` sum. Here's what this might look like:

```
declare @today date = convert(date, getdate());
select
    [Day Total]   = sum(case when [AccountingDate] < dateadd(day,   1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
    [Month Total] = sum(case when [AccountingDate] < dateadd(month, 1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
    [Year Total]  = sum([Amount])
from
    [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
where
    [AccountingDate] >= @today and [AccountingDate] < dateadd(year, 1, @today);
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might also add a universal "where" clause to limit the search to the last year, otherwise the compiler might use a table scan.

Comment: Good idea, @DStanley. I've updated the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: I really like this answer, need to get access to the live database before I can test the results.  Thanks!

Comment: I modified this so that I could test individual results based on set days.  And the latest date available to the database is 2015-04-15.  However, on this day I get NULL as a result and 2015-04-14 gives me a return of same values for day, month, and year when I'm expecting it to add the last 30 days to the month. and then the last 365 days for the year.

Answer (score 1):

Make them all part of a 'super' select:

```
  DECLARE @myDate as datetime
  SET @myDate = '2015-01-1'
SELECT
(select SUM(Amount) 
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(day,1,@myDate) ) as 'Day Total',

(select SUM(Amount) 
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(MONTH,1,@myDate) )  as 'Month Total',

(select SUM(Amount)
from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] 
where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(year,1,@myDate) )  as 'Day Total'
```

Comment: Right on the money! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write each as a sub-query with a surrounding select. I have often found this useful as it allows me to piece together the query one bit at a time.  This will give you `null` in the column values when there is no records - which may not be what you want. Refer to @JoeFarrell's question as he has provided an example of using `case` to turn null into 0.

(Please excuse the strange layout, felt it was worth accentuating the `,`)

```
DECLARE @myDate as datetime
SET @myDate = '2015-01-1'
select 
    (select SUM(sale_total)
    from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
    where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(day,1,@myDate))  as 'Day Total' 
    ,
    (select SUM(sale_total) 
    from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
    where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(MONTH,1,@myDate)) as 'Month Total' 
    ,
    (select SUM(sale_total) 
    from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
    where AccountingDate>=@myDate and AccountingDate<dateadd(year,1,@myDate)) as 'Day Total'
```